# C# : Printing variables and text in a textbox

Tags: c#, printing, textbox

I need  to know the command that I can print a sentence like "the item *Peter* at row *233* and column *1222* is not a number " .

I far as now I have made this:

```
            string[] lineItems = (string[])List[]
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(lineItems[0], (@"^\d*$")))
        textBox2.Text += " The number ,lineItems[0], is bigger than 
10 " + Environment.NewLine;
```

I want to print the array fields that have error. So if it finds something it will print it.

I made a code that correctly prints that there is an error on this line of the array, but I cant print the item of the array.

I need to have an `Environment.NewLine` because I will print many lines.

Thanks ,
George.

Comment: This code does not make any sense.  What are you trying to achieve?  You should never need to have if(true) in your c# code.

Comment: @sheik I want to print the array fields that have error. So if it finds something it will print it. I have correctly printed that there is an error on this line of the array, but I cant print the item of the array.

Comment: please cleanup the code, to get an answer.

Comment: so question is `how to loop through array`? or `how to build a string`?

Comment: I want to print a string in the textbox. Inside the stirng there will be variables, like: " _Peter_ is in line _7_ and row _8_."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (int lineNumber in lineItems)
{
    if (lineNumber > 10)
        textBox2.Text += "The number " + lineNumber + " is bigger than 10\n";
}
```

Something like this should work, (I have not checked the c# code, I am working on a mac at the moment)

Comment: I dont have the reputation needed

Answer (score 2):

```
TextBox2.Text="This is FirstLine\nThis is Second Line";
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not compilable absolutely, but I may be understand what you're asking about.

If you are asking about how to compose the string of text box, by adding new strings to it, based on some desicional condition (regex), you can do folowing, *pseudocode*:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuidler();
if (!Regex.IsMatch(lineItems[i], (@"^\d*$")))
   sb.Append(string.Format(The number ,{0}, is bigger than 10, lineItems[i]) + Environment.NewLine);

textBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

If this is not what you want, just leave the comment, cause it's not very clear from post.

Regards.